# In react hook form with typescript, how can I force the return type of a FieldPath?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

In react hook form, let's say I have this reusable control:

```
function PropertyDropdownControlled<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
    TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
>
```

It can then be used like this where the property "name" is of type TName:

```
<PropertyDropdownControlled<CurrentFormValues> name="Property" />
```

How can I add a typescript constraint to force TFieldValues[TName] to be of a certain type, for example PropertyDTO?